# php foreach, person appearing twice with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So this is my database:

TABLE NAME: user_account

```
   Account_no       Firstname       Lastname       Username       Password
      1              Larry            Bird         larryB         larrylarry
      2              Magic           Johnson       magic         magiclakers
```

TABLE NAME: tbl_items

```
   Item_ID         Item_Name       Quantity       Price       Directory
     1              gown              5           1000         gown.jpg
     2              bridal            3           1500         bridal.png
```

TABLE NAME: tbl_item_availed

```
 Item_availed_ID   Item_ID        Account_no     Date_reserved   Quantity
     1               1               2              9/14/2016        2
     2               2               1              9/14/2016        1
     3               1               2              9/14/2016        1
```

SO yep this are my tables, and I already joined them 3, my problem is this:

CLIENT RESERVATION VIEW:

```
   CLIENT       DETAILS
   Magic        details
   Bird         details
   Magic        details
```

so I just want it to be like this:

```
   CLIENT       DETAILS
   Magic        details
   Bird         details
```

I already got the details area, the only thing is that the CLIENT's name also LOOPS, I want it to be only one, how will I do that? heres my controller code:

```
   <div id="page-wrapper">
   <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>CLIENT</th>
        <th>DETAILS</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post->Firstname ?> <?php echo $post->Lastname; ?> </td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Pages_Controller/show_receipt/<?php echo $post->Username; ?>">details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

The Query as requested in Model form:

```
public function getServicesAvailed($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("tbl_service_type");
    $this->db->join("tbl_service_availed","tbl_service_availed.Service_ID = tbl_service_type.Service_ID");
    $this->db->where('Account_ID',$id);
    $this->db->where('active',1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`group_by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) and modify the code as follow

```
public function getServicesAvailed($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("tbl_service_type");
    $this->db->join("tbl_service_availed","tbl_service_availed.Service_ID = tbl_service_type.Service_ID");
    $this->db->where('Account_ID',$id);
    $this->db->where('active',1);
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_item_availed.user_id');//add this line 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();        
}
```